# Using PointDNS for non-www and handling SSL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, heroku, dns, subdomain

I've been using Heroku to host my app (www.justbooked.com) and godaddy is where the domain is stored. For some reason, recently the non-www version e.g. justbooked.com is no longer working.

It seems like GoDaddy doesn't provide ANAME / ALIAS or other CNAME-style functionality for root-level domains (example.com).

I would like to know how I can get justbooked.com to work like www.justbooked.com. Is this possible with Godaddy in any other way? Bare in mind, I have SSL certs etc...

If this is not possible with GoDaddy, then using something like PointDNS may work, but I'm still not sure how to configure PointDNS with my existing SSL cert.

Any help here would be great, goal is to get justbooked.com (non-www) working!!!

Thanks!

Comment: Both work fine over here (less SSL); try flushing your DNS cache. You don't need to mess with your DNS to get SSL working. If you've [configured everything correctly with Herkou](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ssl), it should just work.

Comment: It seems to be working now.

Answer (score 3):

I guess your problem might already be solved by now, but for the sake of helping people like you and me in the past (found this topic 4 weeks ago when I had the same problem), I'm writing a step-by-step tutorial on how to get PointDNS working for www and non-www domains on HTTPS. **Read all steps, including the notes, before starting.**

1. Create an add-on for PointDNS in your project by the Heroku's UI or by using the CLI command: `heroku addons:create pointdns:developer`
2. Open the Heroku's UI and enter the PointDNS dashboard. Look for the "Nameserver" tab and check out the list of nameservers. Look for the ones that fit the most to you.
3. Copy the recommended number of nameservers (no more, no fewer), go to the place where you bought the domain (in your case GoDaddy) and edit the DNS servers to point for PointDNS. Wait for at least 2 hours for these changes to take effect.
4. Add **both your www and non-www domains** to Heroku custom domains list, either via Heroku's UI or using the CLI commands: `heroku domains:add justbooked.com` and `heroku domains:add www.justbooked.com`
5. Copy both DNS targets that appear by each domain (the one ending with `.herokudns.com`). You can check the DNS targets either by the Heroku's UI or by using the CLI command: `heroku domains`
6. Go to the PointDNS dashboard and add an ALIAS record for the root domain (non-www) and a CNAME record for the www domain; on each one, add the correspondent DNS target that you copied in the previous step. Maybe the records for these 2 domains were created automatically when you added the PointDNS add-on; in that case just edit the DNS targets.
7. Wait for 1 hour more and then Heroku will automatically set an SSL certificate for you using ACM (Automated Certificate Management). If everything went right, you should have both domains working on HTTPS protocol now.

### Notes:

1. If you have more than 1 Heroku app using the same git codebase, you'll need to use the `--app` flag in the Heroku CLI commands.
2. You said you have an existing SSL certificate. If you want to use that instead of the one given by the ACM, you'll need to set up a SSL endpoint. To do that, **before step 4**, create one by using the CLI command: `heroku addons:create ssl:endpoint`. After that, upload your certificate using the command: `heroku certs:add server.crt server.key --type endpoint`. **In step 5**, instead of the `heroku domains` command, use `heroku certs`. Use the endpoint DNS target (the one ending in `.ssl.herokudns.com`) **in step 6**.
3. Once you set up the domains and SSL certificates, you might also want to redirect all HTTP traffic to HTTPS. You can only do that by coding the redirect logic into your application. In the case of Ruby on Rails, you'll need to use `config.force_ssl = true` in your `config/environments/production.rb` or similar.
4. You might see a lot of tutorials using the `.herokuapp.com` link instead of the `.herokudns.com` one as the DNS target in PointDNS. **This might work for HTTP traffic, but your HTTPS sessions will fail.** Use the `.herokudns.com` even if you're only using HTTP (maybe you're using the free hosting plan), because it'll be easier to set up HTTPS later.

### References:

1. [Heroku Dev Center: Custom Domain Names for Apps](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains)
2. [Heroku Dev Center: SSL Endpoint](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ssl-endpoint)
3. [Heroku Help: Can Heroku force an application to use SSL/TLS?](https://help.heroku.com/J2R1S4T8/can-heroku-force-an-application-to-use-ssl-tls)
4. [Heroku Dev Center: PointDNS](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/pointdns) (a bit outdated, but can be a good resource)

Answer (score 0):

While pointing any website via pointdns you can use 2 ways , one is via cname and other is using service like pointDNS. If you want to run SSL specially on naked domain like justbooked.com in your case you need to you pointDNS here

PointDNS configuration is quite easy as you just need to add dns records from godaddy to pointDNS

For SSL , either you can use ACM or add your own certificate in heroku setting.ACM uses let's encrypt SSL which is free but doesnot allow wildcard SSL.